# Map Network Drive in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, network-share, network-drive

I have spend months now trying to get the Visual Basic 2010 codes on how to map a network drive, disconnect them, and re-map network driver.

I will need to be able to map it to the profile folder to something like this:
Full path; “\10.10.10.12\Profile folder".
I need to log in to have access to the network folder `/user:Domainname\UserName Password`,
then confirm if mapping was successful with a message.

After the mapping I will request the profile name and check if such profile folder exists on the network.
If it exists, return a message stating that the profile exists, and delete the profile folder overwriting any folder property like if reading only, etc.

There are other tasks but his is where I am hit a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but maybe the OP is still looking. I wrote an HTA page awhile back to map a network address to a virtual drive. The code is VBScript and so uses the WScript library, which is not a native part of VB.net. See [WScript in VB.Net on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590211/wscript-in-vb-net) for more info on that.

The connect script:

```
SUB doLogOn()
Dim objNetwork, errNum, ojbFSO, strDrive, iNum
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists("\\MyServer\MyFolder\") = False Then
   strDrive = "J:"
   Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
   On Error Resume Next
   objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive strDrive, "\\MyServer\MyFolder", False, "username", "password"
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          Err.Clear
   End If
   Set objFSO = Nothing
   Set objNetwork = Nothing
End If
END SUB
```

Personally, I haven't found code to do the same thing in .Net. The VBScript shown above is pretty primitive; I hope it plus the info on binding WScript gives you an idea or two, though.

Edit: see [Eric Dalnas' code, here](http://www.mredkj.com/vbnet/vbnetmapdrive.html)